# How do I get the tag descriptions column on Data Explorer (SEDE)?

Tags: support, data-explorer

I just want to get the full description of each tag, but the actual table doesn't have any related column. I have also searched by using sp_depends, but no results are retrieved.

Comment: I have an open [feature request on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250490/there-are-no-foreign-keys-constraints-in-the-data-explorer-database) to add the foreign keys info to SEDE. That is already a couple of years old so don't hold your breath ...

Comment: Schema info for SEDE is maintained on MSE in [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tag excerpts and wikis are in the `Posts` table (post types 4 and 5, respectively).

`WikiPostId` and `ExcerptPostId` on the `Tags` table will give you the specific post ids to grab for a given tag.